# How do I set a default picture on a picture control?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a picture control bound to attachment field. When I begin entering a new record, a random picture is populated in the attachment. My intention is to leave the attachment field without any picture unless a user intentionally uploads the file. I have tried the following code with no luck. Any help here?

```
Private Sub Form_Current()

With Me.ItemImage
If Not IsNull(.DefaultPicture) Then
.DefaultPicture = ""
End If
End With

'Another try

If Me.NewRecord Then
ItemName.DefaultPicture = ""
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What does 'no luck' mean - error message, wrong result, nothing happens? By 'picture' control do you mean an image control? I am not familiar with DefaultPicture property. How and where is this set?

Answer (score 0):

Study the *online-help*:

[Attachment.DefaultPicture property (Access)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.attachment.defaultpicture)

> The DefaultPicture property contains (bitmap) or the path and file
>   name of a bitmap or other type of graphic to be displayed.